# add textbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create mcq question with dynamic id by using jquery. but i got stuck when i am defining a unique id for the option of each question. can somebody help me to find way to create unique id for each mcq option? below is my jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
var counter = 2;//question

$("#addQuestion").click(function () {

var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Q'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
      '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >' + '</br>' + 
      '<label>A. </label>'+
      '<input type="text" id="Q'+counter+'choice1">' +
      '<input type="button" value="Add Option" id="'+ counter + '">');

newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


counter++;
 });

 $("#removeQuestion").click(function () {
if(counter==1){
      alert("No question that can be deleted");
      return false;
   }   

counter--;

    $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

 });

 //$("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

// var msg = '';
//for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
 // msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
//}
//      alert(msg);
 //});
});
</script>
</head><body>
```

here is the html

```
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
<div id="TextBoxDiv1">
    <label>Q1 : </label><input type='textbox' id='textbox1' ></br>
    <label>A. <input type='text' id='Q1choice1'>
    <input type='button' value='Add Option' id='1'>
</div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Add Question' id='addQuestion'>
<input type='button' value='Remove Question' id='removeQuestion'>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user2310289 i got stuck in creating dynamic id for the mcq option.

Comment: I don't see what is wrong - counter is a global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the var counter  before document.ready

```
Does not work: 
$(document).ready(function () {
        var counter = 2;//question



  Works:
var counter = 2;//question
$(document).ready(function () {
```

EDIT: counter is only global is defined outside $(document).ready

Answer (score 0):

Try append newTextBoxDiv in your code:

```
   .... var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))...
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
    $('body').append(newTextBoxDiv);
  ...  newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Q'....
```

**$('body').append(newTextBoxDiv);**

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
  var counter = $("#TextBoxesGroup div").length;
```